# How to build a Map<Object, List<Object>> map from a List<Object>

Tags: list, java-8, guava

I build a idMap as follow:

```
class Item {
    private int id;
    private int skuId;
    //some getter and setter
}

Map<Integer, List<Integer>> buildIdMap(List<Item> items) {

    Map<Integer, List<Integer> idMap = Maps.newHashMap();

    for (Item item : items) {
        if (!idMap.contains(item.getId())) {
            idMap.put(item.getId(), List.newArrayList());
        }
        idMap.put(item.getId(), item.getSkuId());
    }
    return idMap;
}
```

how can I utilize guava or java8 to do the same thing?

Comment: `Map<Integer, List<Integer>` you have multiple syntax errors like this (no `>`), and multiple missing semi-colons. Your method also doesn't return anything.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-

Comment: what is `item.getSkuId()`? also this code makes little sense, think about it: if your map does not contain that `id` - you put it in via `idMap.put(item.getId(), List.newArrayList())`, only exactly after to override that value via `idMap.put(item.getId(), item.getSkuId())` - as the code is, I am voting to close it as unclear, once you update it and make a bit more sense, I will retract the vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do it like so using Java8,

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> idMap = items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getId, 
                Collectors.mapping(Item::getSkuId, Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score -1):

## Use Guava's [`Multimaps.index(Iterable<V>,Function<? super V,K>)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Function-):

```
Multimap<Integer, Item> buildIdMap(List<Item> items) {
  return Multimaps.index(items, Item::getId);
}
```

It's not exactly what you asked, I reckon, but it will do the job better than you would expect doing your method.

Comment: and what about `item.getSkuId()` whatever that is?

Comment: well, I did not down vote, but was kind of expecting this knowing SO... even if this is a good approach, may be